# Swift thinks that variable in Structure is optional

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I made simple post making project based on Firebase. I save post into Firebase like this:

```
let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newPostImageView.image!, 0.5)//Take photo from imageview
        let metadata = FIRStorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"//Define post image path

        let postId = "\(currentUser.generalDetails.uid)\(NSUUID().uuidString)"//Generate postId
        let imagePath = "postImages\(postId)/postPic.jpg"

        storageRef.child(imagePath).put(data!, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error) in
            if error == nil {

                let postRef = self.databaseRef.child("posts").childByAutoId()


                let post = Post(postImageUrl: String(describing: metadata?.downloadURL()), profileImageUrl: self.currentUser.generalDetails.profileImageURL, postId: postId, content: self.newPostTextView.text, username: self.currentUser.generalDetails.userName)
                postRef.setValue(post.toAnyObject())     

            }else {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            } 
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

`currentUser.generalDetails. ...` is singleton I have.

1. However, it sets `"postImageUrl"` into Firebase like

> "Optional(https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/"

I do not understand why, since I do not have optionals. Is image from imagePicker optional?

Comment: Why do you use `String(describing:)`? `downloadURL()` is nullable, could be why...

Comment: I did it only because Xcode was complaining. And asks me to put it in there.

Comment: `String(describing:)` transforms *anything* into a string, and is usually *not* the correct solution to make it compile.

Comment: Ohh.. Okay. So I fixed it like this:
`let downloadUrl = metadata!.downloadURL()`
and set it as `postImageUrl: (downloadUrl?.absoluteString)!`

But what about the second problem, when it doesn't set any values but puts empty string in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think swift works best when using `if let` to unwrap and test all needed preconditions for a block.

In this example you need an unwrapped image URL as a string that is not empty.

It's possible to set all of this up.

```
if let downloadUrl = metadata?.downloadURL() { // Unwrap the URL.
    if let imageUrl = downloadUrl.absoluteString { // URL as a string.
        if !imageUrl.isEmpty { // URL must not be empty.
        }
    }
}
```

Luckily, this can all be done on one line.

```
if let imageUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString, !imageUrl.isEmpty {
}
```

Placed in context, this gives the following.

```
storageRef.child(imagePath).put(data!, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error) in
    if let imageUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString, !imageUrl.isEmpty {
        let postRef = self.databaseRef.child("posts").childByAutoId()

        let post = Post(postImageUrl: imageUrl,
                        profileImageUrl: self.currentUser.generalDetails.profileImageURL,
                        postId: postId,
                        content: self.newPostTextView.text,
                        username: self.currentUser.generalDetails.userName)

        postRef.setValue(post.toAnyObject())     
    } else if error != nil {
        print(error!.localizedDescription)
    } else {
        print("Unknown error")
    }
}
```

Finally, we can use a `guard` statement to exit early. This reduces the level of indent in the main line of code.

```
storageRef.child(imagePath).put(data!, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error) in
    guard let imageUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString, !imageUrl.isEmpty else {
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")
        return
    }

    let postRef = self.databaseRef.child("posts").childByAutoId()

    let post = Post(postImageUrl: imageUrl,
                    profileImageUrl: self.currentUser.generalDetails.profileImageURL,
                    postId: postId,
                    content: self.newPostTextView.text,
                    username: self.currentUser.generalDetails.userName)

    postRef.setValue(post.toAnyObject())     
}
```

Comment: Wow.. Thank you. It did work. And thanks for the mini tutorial and for some tips. And it is yes better not to force things. However the second problem is still in the air. For some reason, If I do not go into profile viewcontroller it thinks user values are ""(empty strings). Do you know fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try:-

```
let metaURLString = "\(metaData!.downloadURL())"

        if metaURLString != "" {

            let post = Post(postImageUrl: metaURLString, profileImageUrl: self.currentUser.generalDetails.profileImageURL, postId: postId, content: self.newPostTextView.text, username: self.currentUser.generalDetails.userName)
            postRef.setValue(post.toAnyObject())

        }
```

Comment: It does same at least for me. But I fixed it like this: `let downloadUrl = metadata!.downloadURL()` and set it as `postImageUrl: (downloadUrl?.absoluteString)!`

But the problem is it sets username and user profile image as empty string for some reason.